# HttpVerbs.Get and parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the following action :

```
public class IntegrationController : Controller
    {
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ContentResult Feed(string feedKey)
        {
           ...
        }
}
```

I have tried to use this URL :

```
http://MyServer/Integration/Feed/MyTest
```

but `feedKey` is null? Does this have something to do with routes?

Edit 1 :

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Ad", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "TreeEditing", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "AdCategory", action = "Add", name = string.Empty, id = -1 }
            );
```

Edit 2 :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "IntegrationFeed", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{feedKey}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Integration", action = "Feed", name = string.Empty, feedKey = "" }
            );
```

Comment: What routes have you defined?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a route defined for `feedKey`? Using the default routes, the following should work (change `feedKey` to `id`).

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ContentResult Feed(string id)
    {
       // ...
    }
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! How would it look like if I was to create a new route?